# How to excecute a php file using ng-click

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i have a php file named "sms.php".
This php program creates a file in my desktop.

how do i call this php file using angularjs?

i tried something like this

JS

```
$scope.getsms = function ($http) {
 $http.get('http://localhost/mobilesms/sms.php').success(function (data) {
 });
};

$scope.addTripsheet = function () { 
 $scope.getsms()
 };
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addTripsheet();" class="btn btn-success noPrint">Book</button>
```

Comment: i made a mistake typing here but i typed it properly in my code

Comment: I think you have a problem with dependency injection https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di